# How do I attain the item in the column "street number" alongside the minimum value from "Occupants"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I use the below SQL Query to grab the lowest value from *Occupants*. How do I grab the value alongside it within the *streetnumber* column. So I want to grab value *112*

```
SELECT MIN(Occupants) AS LowestOccupants FROM Book;
```

Table(Book):

```
StreetNumber  |  StreetName  |  Occupants

111               Cheese            6
112               Bacon             5
113               Burger            10
114               Seconds           93
115               Suit              12
```

Comment: Are you looking for a generic solution? Why tag `mysql` **and** `sql-server`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the streets that have the minimum number of occupants you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   book b1 
WHERE  b1.occupants = (SELECT Min(b2.occupants) 
                       FROM   book b2)
```

This will return all rows there the occupancy has a minimum, i.e. if 111 and 112 both had 5 occupants it will return them both.

Comment: I just want to return the relevant StreetNumber, not the entire row.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would want to do this, can you explain more? Is there a unique identifier or primary key on the table?

To directly answer your question you could use:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [StreetNumber] FROM [Book] ORDER BY [Occupants] ASC
```

Comment: This would only work in SQL Server, not in MySQL (you'd have to use `LIMIT 1` then). Also: I think you mean `ASC`, not `DESC` :-)

Comment: Correct! :) I was unsure which as the question tagged both.